# Distributed network made of identical application

Tags: tcp

I've come here with quite philosophical problem:

suppose we have two identical application, with similar range of settings.
and we'd like these application can communicate via sockets.

As far as I know in point-to-point application one of them should be active(client) and passiv(server) i.e. client do "connect" and the server should be in state of "accept". This lead us to necessity to know who is active and who isn't before we run them.

As I've previously mentioned I want make this application identical. And let two identical application can be connected throw net, making somehow smart decisions Who is Who.

This question is considered due to the fact that I want each new application can be connected to the net of other applications with just knowing ip adress  of one of them.

Disclaimer: It's not a malware. It's a transport layer of ERP system.

I would be very pleased for any ideas, link etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

- Designate one app to always be the server.  It starts up listening on some port, and the other app when it starts up, will try to connect to the server repeatedly until it is successful.
- Have both act as both a server and a client.  App on one host starts up and tries to connect to the other host, and if it can't then it starts up a server listening for a connection from the other host.  The app on the other host does the same.  Should add in retries to avoid race conditions.
- Have them each act as clients and connect to a third server.  They then communicate through that server, or that server tells them how to communicate with one another (the server might for example tell one app to be a server, and tells the other app to be a client).

Comment: addition to #2: if they both act as the server when they start up and then attempt to connect to each other the only issue you'd have to deal with is if both succeed and then solving that just requires that one of the connections must be dropped.